# converting dates in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a date in an h3 tag which I am trying to grab and convert to another date using some functionality from my code behind files. How do I accomplish this in jquery?

HTML

```
<div id="firstweekwrapper" class="weekcontainer">
                        <div id="day1" class="daytile daytilefirst">
                            <h3 id="day1date" class="dateh3"><%=FirstTradingDayInMonth(DateTime.Now.Date).ToLongDateString()%></h3><br />
                            <p id="day1equities"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1equitytargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1equityactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day1options"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Options</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1optiontargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Options</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1optionactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day1futures"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1futuretargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day1futureactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="day2" class="daytile">
                            <h3 id="day2date" class="dateh3"></h3><br />
                            <p id="day2equities"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2equitytargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2equityactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day2options"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Options</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2optiontargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Options</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2optionactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day2futures"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2futuretargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day2futureactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                        </div>
                         <div id="day3" class="daytile">
                            <h3 id="day3date" class="dateh3"></h3><br />
                            <p id="day3equities"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3equitytargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Equities</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3equityactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day3options"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Options</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3optiontargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Options</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3optionactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                            <p id="day3futures"><span class="targettext"> <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> Target PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3futuretargetvalue" class="targettext"></span><br /><span class="actualtext">Actual <span class="bluetext">Futures</span> PnL:&nbsp;</span><span id="day3futureactualvalue" class="actualtext"></span></p>
                        </div>
```

I am trying to set the day2date id's value to the next business day using the AddBusinessDay function from my code behind file. I am somewhat new to using jquery so im not certain how to incorporate using vb.net code from the code behind file.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with jQuery? Why not just do it from your VB.Net code?

Comment: since i have 22 days of these i was trying to avoid having runat server tags on every h3 tag and do it via jquery. I also can add the code in the tag itself as ive done with the first day but it looks unwieldly and i thought jquery implementation would be more simplistic

Comment: I also have to reference each prior h3 tag to get the prior date to check for the next business day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think you should do this server-side, but if you're intent on using javascript to do this, you could do something like this:

- Parse the date string into a date object
- Add a day to it
- Convert the day back into a formatted date string

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/7MCAb/)

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var _date = Date.parse($("#day1date").text());
    $("#day2date").text(FormattedDate(_date, 1));
    $("#day3date").text(FormattedDate(_date, 2));
    $("#day4date").text(FormattedDate(_date, 3));
    $("#day5date").text(FormattedDate(_date, 4));
    $("#day6date").text(FormattedDate(_date, 5));
});

var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December");

function FormattedDate(_date, _addDays) {
    var d = _date + (86400000 * _addDays); //86400000ms = 1day
    d = new Date(d);
    var returnDate = d_names[d.getDay()] + ", " + m_names[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear();
    return returnDate;
}
```

Comment: ty, i was moving along and this will help me. the problem im runing into doing it serverside is everyday has to be tested against the prior h3 tags date Im not sure how to access that  I was using <%= AddBusinessDays(FirstTradingDayInMonth(DateTime.Now.Date).ToLongDateString()) but that only works for the second date, i cant pass the second date to the next tag